# Updating themes customized by users

Tags: multisite, themes

Can I safely update a theme if a user has *only* modified it through THEMES > CUSTOMIZED? I know that a user has to clone and create a child theme if they want to edit the php/css/javascript files directly. But, if the only modifications were through the THEMES > CUSTOMIZED, would there changes remain in place after a theme update?

[image]

Comment: Maybe, why don't you pull the site down to a local development environment and test it?  There's no way we can answer the question as is.

Comment: Do you mean the customiser? I'm not aware of a 'customised' option

Comment: Perhaps. I've added a screen shot to show how they are accessing it.

Comment: I'll play with the idea of exporting to a dev instance on a vagrant install. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **yes**.

Long answer:

The Customize API uses one of two methods for storing customizations: the Settings API or the Theme Mods API (the latter being the default method). Thus, all changes are saved to the database, either as a Theme-defined option, or via `theme_mods_{themeslug}`.

When the Theme is updated, the Theme files in `/wp-content/themes/{themeslug}` are deleted and replaced, but the database entries in `wp_options` remain untouched.